# How to remove embebed document via its schema in Mongoose (MEAN)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean.io

I'm having trouble with mongoose embeded documents and removing one of them. In my system I have a set of arduino's which records the mac adress. Besides the MAC address each arduino can have a set of sensors and a set of actuators. These sensors and actuators are defined in a seperate document. Below are the scheme's:

**Arduino**

```
var arduinoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
Arduino_id : {type:String, required:true},
Sensors : [Sensor],
Actuators : [Actuator]
}, {versionKey: false});
```

**Sensor**

```
var sensorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Type : {type:String, required:true}
}, {versionKey: false});
```

**Actuator**

```
var actuatorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
Type : String
}, {versionKey: false});
```

The problem is now that I want the system to be able to remove sensors seperately. So I want it to be able to remove one of the actuators from the actuator models. This should als remove the actuator with that ID from the arduino I first posted it to. I use the following code to create the actuator and Arduino:

```
var ard = new Arduino();

ard.Arduino_id = req.body.Arduino_id;

if(req.body.Actuators !== undefined){
    for(var i = 0; i < req.body.Actuators.length; i++){
        var actuator = new Actuator();
        actuator.Type = req.body.Actuators[i].Type;
        actuator.save(function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log("Database failure - Couldn't add actuator!");
            }
        });
        ard.Actuators.push(actuator);
    }}

if(req.body.Sensors !== undefined){
    for(i = 0; i < req.body.Sensors.length; i++){
        var sensor = new Sensor();
        sensor.Type = req.body.Sensors[i].Type;
        sensor.save(function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log("Database failure - Couldn't add sensor!");
            }
        });
        ard.Sensors.push(sensor);
    }
}

ard.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
    } else {
        res.json(ard);
    }
});
```

Finally I've been trying for myself. If I try to remove it from the collection with the code I have below the actuator is actually removed from the collection. It's not removed from the arduino itself though!

```
Sensor.remove({_id : req.params.id}, function(err) {
  if(err){
    res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});
```

I hope you can help me!

With kind regards,
Danny Verpoort

Comment: Do you have a collection for each of the schemas described but you also embed two of the schemas into the third?

Comment: Yea basically I embedded the sensor and actuator into the arduino. But I use  the schemes model in the controller as well.

Comment: Ah, any reason you aren't using references for the embedded document?

Comment: Ohhh am I basically duplicating the entry now between the arduino and the other two? Lemme see if I can get the referencing in. I'll get back after I tried.

Comment: References will help to have only one point of authority regarding sensors and actuators (their respective collections) but you will need to remove both the item from the collection and the corresponding reference from the subdocument array in the arduino collection. There is no magic that removes them both.